# OpenCV: cv::imshow() freezes

Tags: opencv, freeze

I've written some code, which currently consists of two windows to show different stages of some processing algorithm. Quite simply, I've created the two windows with `cv::namedWindow()`, and I'm displaying the `cv::Mat` with `cv::imshow()`. I'm having an issue where every now and again, randomly (but not always), `cv::imshow()` refuses to update the two windows. The program hasn't hung, and I can see that it is still working and processing the incoming frames (as I'm printing stuff into the terminal to show this), it's just that the windows aren't showing the new frames. I've included `cv::waitKey(2)` after each call to `cv::imshow()`, however this doesn't help.

This is very annoying, and I can't seem to find anything online. This doesn't always happen, but it does more often than not. Sometimes it takes a few minutes, sometimes it takes a few seconds.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (and Ubuntu 11.10 - this happens on both of my machines with two different cameras) with OpenCV 2.3.1.

Comment: It is very likely an issue with the incoming frames. you could also consider checking the values of random independent elements in the Mat to see that they are indeed correct. Please post the code that causes this issue.

Comment: Try a bigger delay: waitKey(20); It may be that your computer cannot process the imshow() request in the 2 milliseconds.

Comment: @vasile: This doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @go4sri: The code is quite large and fairly intricate. I thought it may be that I had missed a .release() or something somewhere, but I just checked this and I haven't. I'm reusing the same variables, but the frames themselves are captured by a different thread and placed on a buffer. I'm not sure what could be going wrong as everything else works just fine, and some of that would depend on some of the elements of `cv::Mat`.

Comment: @vasile the waitKey is delay **after** the image has been displayed and does not include the time to load and display the image.

Comment: OK. Try writing the Mat to a file using imwrite(). Open the file in an external image viewer to see if it opens correctly.

Comment: @go4sri the code that processes the window display is called while the main thread is in waitKey. Actually, in that function are processed the window events, like mouse move, window move, display, etc.

Comment: I also tried with `cv::imwrite()` to double check the saved images. What I feed to my visualizer thread (class) is updating but inside `cv::Mat image` that I would like to show using `cv::mshow()` is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I've been able to get around that issue is by using 
    cv::destroyWindow()
after calling a window.  This works well if you're just showing a sequence of images, but not so well if you're showing video.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm showing frames from a camera real-time, so that won't work.

Comment: could you clarify where exactly use `cv::destroyWindow()`? Does that come right after `cv::waitKey()`?